# SUM with JOIN tables in MYSQL gives wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, join

Maybe someone could really help me here. I need some guidance. How come when I try to do a SUM in a column from a JOIN table the SUM form the main table returns wrong results? Let's say if sum from table A is 6 but there are 3 records that join with table B then the results turns from 6 to 18.. I just can't seem to get it. Thank you

```
    SELECT SUM(tm_hours) AS total_hours, 
           SUM(drive_time) AS drive_time,
           STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(tm_date),WEEK(tm_date),' Monday'), '%X%V %W') AS weeks 
      FROM `bhds_timecard` 
 LEFT JOIN bhds_mileage 
        ON bhds_timecard.case_no = bhds_mileage.case_no 
     WHERE bhds_timecard.ds_id = '3' AND tm_date BETWEEN '2016-03-16' AND '2016-03-31' 
  GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(tm_date), WEEK(tm_date))
```

Output should look something like that I modified the query but I am still getting wrong drive time. drive time for the firs week should be 55 that is because it is only taking the drive time from one day

[image]

Comment: Can you add: some sample data for table A and B, an example result of what you're looking to get, and an example of what you're getting now?

Comment: Also, can you post the schema of the two tables you're joining on.  you can use the command `show create table bhds_mileage`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(hours) as total_hours, SUM(drive_time), weeks 
   FROM (  SELECT tm_hours AS hours, 
                  SUM(drive_time) AS drive_time,
                  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(tm_date),
                  WEEK(tm_date),' Monday'), '%X%V %W') AS weeks,
                  bhds_timecard.case_no
               FROM `bhds_timecard` 
               LEFT JOIN bhds_mileage 
                  ON bhds_timecard.case_no = bhds_mileage.case_no 
               WHERE bhds_timecard.ds_id = '3' 
                    AND tm_date BETWEEN '2016-03-16' AND '2016-03-31' 
               GROUP BY weeks, bhds_timecard.case_no
        ) as innersums
    GROUP by weeks;
```

Comment: Thank you Ray yes you're right I tried that but that doesn't solve the issue with the sum being multiplied by the amount of records from the join table :/

Comment: @joanb When you group, each record meeting the grouping will be part of total in the SUM.  I'm assuming there is a single `bhds_timecard.case_no` for many (or no) `bhds_mileage.case_no` entries.  Your query is asking for the sum of hours and drive time by year/week for a given bhds_mileage.case_no  with  `bhds_timecard.ds_id = '3' AND tm_date BETWEEN '2016-03-16' AND '2016-03-31' `.    Is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: I see what you are saying, so I should be joining the tables with a unique value as the id from timecard table?

Comment: @joanb I guess the first thing I'd do is to step back and add to your post an explanation of what you're trying to show with this query like: "looking to show cases by week, blah, blah, blah"  and add to your post an example of the output you're expecting, the schema of the tables being used and maybe some sample data (without sensitive info in it).

Comment: I am trying to get the totals hours between given dates 2016-03-01 and 2016-03-31 grouped by week. this is good. Output right now is fine, total hours for week 1 is 6 for week 2 is 15 and for week 3 is 6 again. Now what I want to add is the drive time that is in another table I guess I can just run another query and get the data from there I was just wondering if this was possible to do in a single query.

Comment: @joanb ah... I see, the total hours are in your `tm_hours` table, the mileage is in the `bhds_mileage`  table

Comment: @joanb  you can do an inner select statement to group by the drive time by weeks and case, then group by and sum the hours grouped by just weeks.  See my update (may need some tweaking)